# Doxygen document struct members with attributes

Tags: c, struct, doxygen

I have a `struct` with one of its fields annotated with [gcc type attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes).

```
struct str {
    size_t size; /**< Size of string. */
    char string[1] __attribute__ ((aligned(__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__))); /**< String. */
};
```

When I run doxygen on this code, struct member `string` is referenced not as `Data Field`, but as a `Public Member Function`. How do I make doxygen list this field as a `Data Field`?

P.S. I have string `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES` present in my `Doxyfile`.

Comment: Are those round brackets at the beginning and end all necessary? Did you have a look at the chapter "Preprocessing" in the manual (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html), here are some remarks about e.g. `__attribute__`.

Comment: I missed this. I will now examine this chapter. Thanks.

Comment: @albert adding `PREDEFINED = "__attribute__ (arg)=" "aligned(arg)=` did not work. Probably because of double braces, it expands to `__attribute__ (())`. But braces are mandatory.

Comment: Is it correct that the line `char string[1] __attribute__ ((aligned(__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__)));` could read `char string[1];` (for the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case it is correct that for the documentation the line

`char string[1] __attribute__ ((aligned(__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__)));`

can be

`char string[1];`

It would be sufficient to define in the doxygen configuration file:

`PREDEFINED             = __attribute__((x))=`

Comment: I had to set MACRO_EXPANSION = YES and  EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES